What does the blue note symbol mean in Rhythm Festival?
In Taiko no Tatsujin: Rhythm Festival, The Song below random in Taiko Mode has a little blue note with a yellow thing in the bottom left, does this mean explicit language? That would be surprising as I haven't seen any other ones. I also know it doesn't mean New as that says New in a Orange BANG! thing in the Top Right of the Song.


Could you take a screenshot? I can't seem to find any blue notes with yellow things.

oh thats strange its there for me? I'll get a Screenshot next time I remember!

Yes, I have it also are you on Switch cus thats what im on:
ill put the picture in the topic

hello does anyone know?

If you haven't gotten an answer, it means nobody knows. I've seen it before but I have no clue how to trigger it.

... or the right person hasn't seen it yet.

how to trigger what?

How to make it appear

That symbol means it is your "My Battle Song", used in online battles. This used to be one of the modes used in ranked matches, but is now only available in Online Room Match. Although displayed in other modes, it is not relevant to offline play.
It's set to Natsumatsuri by default as it is the first song in the game.
